# How do I know if a enyo.Model was modified?

Tags: javascript, enyo

I have this code
but when I clicked the Button Test , don't enter the function modelChanged in my App,only enter when de model was create
the code is in this link: http://jsfiddle.net/bs38A/16/

```
enyo.kind({
    name: "App",
    bindings: [
        {from: ".model.foo", to: ".$.notFoo.content"}
    ],
    components: [
        {classes: "onyx-toolbar-inline", components:[
            {content: "model's 'foo' property:"},
            {name: "notFoo"}
        ]},
        {kind: "onyx.Button", content: "Test", ontap: "test"}
    ],
    test: function() {
        var m = this.model;
        m.set("foo", "model");
    },
    modelChanged: function(){
        this.inherited(arguments);
        console.log("Change Model");
    }
});
enyo.kind({
    name: "MyModel",
    kind: "enyo.Model"
});
var app = new App().renderInto(document.body);
var model = new MyModel({foo: "bar"});
app.set("model", model);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code currently only fires once (when you do `app.set("model", model);`.  Because changing a property on the model doesn't actually change the `model` property of `App`, the `modelChanged` event isn't fired.

If you want to be notified whenever any property of the model changes you'll want to use a different method. What you want to look at is the documentation for the Event Emitter mixin: http://enyojs.com/docs/latest/#/mixin/enyo.EventEmitter

You'll want to do something like this:

```
create: function() {
    this.inherited(arguments);
    this.model.on("*", this.modelUpdated, this);
},
modelUpdated: function(sender, e, props) {
    this.log("Model was updated");
}
```

That will monitor for any changes.  You may want to get more specific, such as using `"change"` instead of `"*"`.  If you want to monitor changes to specific properties on a model then you will want to subclass Model and put a change handler in the model.

Answer (score 0):

this is because the modelChanged() function is executed when the model property of App changes/is set.  Since enyo.Model isn't an enyo.Component, it doesn't get the automatic propertyChanged functionality.  Check on how to add observers here http://enyojs.com/docs/latest/developer-guide/building-apps/managing-data/building-data-driven-apps.html#observers

Comment: modelChanged should be called whenever using the 'set' method to set the model property, but not when setting a property of the model.  The changed method doesn't require a component.

Comment: Ah, it does require enyo.Object, though.

Comment: Models do support 'changed' methods even though they are not objects.